# Library similar to BeautifulSoup and "HTML Agility Pack" but for C or Java?

Tags: java, c, html-parsing

I am preparing some custom performance tests against a legacy application that outputs nonstandard HTML (missing tags, duplicate quotes, missing quotes, the works) that can't be changed right now for all the usual reasons.

I am looking for a library similar to BeautifulSoup or "HTML Agility Pack" that can be called from C or Java on a UNIX host.

We'll build some test scaffolding and then start redesigning and reimplementing, but I need some baseline measurements first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Tidy](http://tidy.sourceforge.net/) or [JTidy](http://sourceforge.net/projects/jtidy/)

Answer (score 2):

TagSoup - http://home.ccil.org/~cowan/XML/tagsoup/

Comment: I wish I could accept both answers.

Answer (score 0):

jsoup - http://jsoup.org/

> jsoup: Java HTML Parser
>   jsoup is a Java library for working with real-world HTML. It provides a very convenient API for extracting and manipulating data, using the best of DOM, CSS, and jquery-like methods.